# Find a column name in first row and replace with different name excel

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

I have around 300 column in excel sheet. Each column have column name in first  row. Every time I am manually searching and changing the column names. Now I need to automate this task. All column names are in first row of excel.

Ex:  whenever I find the column 'category' I need to change with 'cat' name etc.

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code.

Comment: I dont know about vb code. please let me know if you know anything.

Comment: Style Color Code
Style Code
Name
Colour
Main Category
Category 1
Category 2
Category 3
Category4
Category5

Comment: Style Color Code
Style Code
Name
Colour
Main Category
Category 1
Category 2
Category 3
Category4
Category5  These columns needs to be changed with different name

Comment: @Thej There is a way to do what you want in an automate way, but Stack Overflow is not a site do create a code for you. We can just help you to fix what is wrong in your actual code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. Start by taking the [2-minute tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: how does excel know what column name to replace with for what?